# boost.python: calling member function of c++ instance from embedded interpretter

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I'm trying to add Python scripting capabilities to my application using `boost.python`. What I would like to do is to use Python to evaluate simple expressions, on specific C++ class instances, allocated in my C++ application.

I have written a Python wrapper for a simple class in C++:

```
class pyTest1
{
public: 
    pyTest1():i(1),f(3.14){}

    int getint() { return i; }
    void setint(int val) { i = val; }

    float getfloat() { return f; }
    void setfloat(float val) { f = val; }

private:
    int i;
    float f;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pyTestSpace)
{
    class_<pyTest1>("pyTest1", init<>())
        .def("getint", &pyTest1::getint)
        .def("setint", &pyTest1::setint)
        .def("getfloat", &pyTest1::getfloat)
        .def("setfloat", &pyTest1::setfloat)
    ;
}
```

Given an instance of `pyTest1`:

```
pyTest1 *testInstance = new pyTest1;
```

I would like to evaluate an expression like this using embedded Python:

```
result = math.cos(testInstance->getfloat())
```

Assuming that the class instance and the expression (as a string) is passed in to a C++ function like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <graminit.h>

void UseEmbedPython(std::string exp, pyTest1* obj)
{
    Py_Initialize();

    initpyTestSpace();

    PyObject *pDictionary = PyDict_New();

    PyDict_SetItemString(pDictionary, "__builtins__", PyEval_GetBuiltins() );
    PyRun_String("import math", file_input, pDictionary, pDictionary );

    //Need help here!
    //Assuming exp is something like "result = math.cos(obj->getfloat())"
    //How do I make obj's functions accessible to Python interpretter?

    PyRun_String(exp.c_str(), file_input, pDictionary, pDictionary ); 

    PyObject *pResult = PyDict_GetItemString(pDictionary, "result" );

    double result;
    PyArg_Parse(pResult, "d", &result );

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: The `initpyTestSpace()` should already be taking care of the methods being available. What I don't see is construction of the object itself.

Comment: The object is passed in to `UseEmbedPython()`. The question is how to make the pointer `obj` and its functions visible to the interpreter such that they can be used in a python expression.

Comment: There are two, *separate*, issues. Making `obj` visible and making it's methods visible. It's methods already *are* visible (`initpyTestSpace` ensured that), you need to make the object itself visible. To do that you need to wrap it in `PyObject` and add it to `pDictionary`. I don't know the exact function though.